# Primefaces Menubar not rendering properly

Tags: primefaces, submenu

I have a problem in rendering the page with layoutunit in which top layoutunit is having a Menubar with few submenu and menuitems.
its not rendering properly in browser. Please see the attached screen shot of expected and actual page
Earlier, it was rendering properly in the Chrome, but not in firefox and IE. but, now its not rendering as expected in any of the browser

master-layout.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <title>SAMPLE</title>
            </f:facet>
            <ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
                href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/themes/overcast/overcast.css"></link>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
                href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/style/my-style.css"></link>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{layoutBean.handleToggle}" />
                <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{layoutBean.handleClose}" />
                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Track-!T"
                    resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"
                    id="top">
                    <h:form id="topform">
                        <ui:include src="main-menu-bar.xhtml" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom"
                    resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"
                    id="bottom">
                    <h:form id="bottomform">
                        <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left"
                    resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true"
                    id="left">
                    <h:form id="leftform">
                        <ui:insert name="side-menu-bar" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right"
                    resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" id="right"
                    style="height:auto">
                    <h:form id="rightform">
                        <ui:insert name="rightPanel" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="center">
                    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
                        closable="true" />
                    <h:form id="myform">
                        <ui:insert name="content" />
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

main-menu-bar.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <p:menubar id="mainmenubar">
        <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon-note" id="filemenu">
            <p:menuitem value="Customer" />
            <p:menuitem value="Enquiry" />
            <p:menuitem value="Job" />
            <p:menuitem value="Agent"
                action="#{agentController.renderCreateAgentForm}" process="filemenu" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Tools" icon="ui-icon-wrench">
            <p:menuitem value="Back-up Data" />
            <p:menuitem value="Restore Data" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Settings" icon="ui-icon-gear">
            <p:menuitem value="Register Product" />
            <p:menuitem value="Master Data"
                action="#{countryRegionController.renderCreateCountryRegionForm}" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Help" icon="ui-icon-help">
            <p:menuitem value="Project" />
            <p:menuitem value="Other" />
        </p:submenu>
        <p:submenu label="Quit" icon="ui-icon-power">
            <p:submenu label="Customer" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="Project" />
                <p:menuitem value="Other" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Open" />
            <p:separator />
            <p:menuitem value="Quit" />
        </p:submenu>
        <f:facet name="options">
            <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" />
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:menubar>
</ui:composition>
```

[image: Properly Rendered- expected]

[image: Not rendered properly-actual]

Please text here what could be the problem and the solution ..Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put `<h:form id="topform">` inside `main-menu-bar.xhtml` ?

Comment: No. i checked with that too. but, no use. I'm not sure, but i think its something wrong with <ul> tag when html is generated. coz, in the picture, you can notice the all the menuitems are displayed by default with BULLETS. did u try this code in ur machine?

Comment: Lamq, When I checked the primefaces 4.0 dependency, it has dependency with el-api version 2.2. But, I have been supplying el-api older version in pom.xml. So, I removed this one and its working perfectly alright now.. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did an older EL version result in this? Would be very weird... Them most likely there must have been errors either in the browser console or the server